# python parse cpp code and find if statements

Tags: python, parsing

I am writing a cpp code parser program in python. I need to find different syntax constructs in the cpp source code. I have already figured out how to find operations: function call, assignment, data input and output. Now I need to find conditional constructs in the code. Branching should be taken into account. That is, there may be several else ifs in the source code, there may or may not be an else block. I need to get the condition of the construct and the body of the construct for further parsing of this block of code.

In general, all this parsing is necessary to improve the graphical representation of the code. My university requires you to provide a code diagram. I am already tired of doing it and decided to optimize this process.

I have such a code, but it works quite strangely. Please forgive me for being new to Python, I am learning c similar languages.

```py
def raw_parse_if(code_part : str) -> Tuple[list[Tuple[str, str]], str]:
    else_body : str
    statements : list[Tuple[str, str]]

    code = code.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")

    while "if(" in code:

        start_index = code.index("if(") + 2

        end_index = code.index(")") + 1

        condition = code[start_index:end_index]

        body_start_index = code.index("{", end_index) + 1

        next_code = code[body_start_index:]
        next_condition_index = next_code.index("else")
        next_condition_code = next_code[next_condition_index:]
        body_end_index = code.index("}")

        body = code[body_start_index:body_end_index]

        statements.append((condition, body))

        code = code[body_end_index + 1:]
    if "else" in code:
        else_body = code.replace("else{","").split("}")[0]


    return statements, else_body
```

I also have an example of the input data and the expected result:

input:

```py
code = '''
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    if (x > 0) {
        std::cout << "x is positive";
    } else if (x == 0) {
        std::cout << "x is zero";
    } else if (x == 3) {
        std::cout << "x is zero";
    } else if (x == 5) {
        std::cout << "x is zero";
    } 
    else {
        std::cout << "x is negative";
    }
    return 0;
}
'''
```

output:

```py
[("x>0", "std::cout << "x is positive""),
("x == 0", "std::cout << "x is zero""),
("x == 3", "std::cout << "x is zero"),
("x == 5", "std::cout << "x is zero"")]
else body: "std::cout << "x is negative""
```

P.S in the end I want to create a markup block like this for the circuit generation (this is of course unrelated to the question, but still for a general understanding of the problem):
([Also here is the program I plan to use for rendering](https://github.com/viktor-zin/afce))

```
 <if cond="x > 0">
      <branch>
        <pre cond="x &lt; n">
          <branch/>
        </pre>
      </branch>
      <branch>
        <for from="0" to="n - 1" var="i">
          <branch>
            <process text="func()"/>
          </branch>
        </for>
      </branch>
    </if>
```

Comment: Using the `in` operator and the `index` method to "parse" a structured language is going to be extremely error-prone. Consider using a proper parser (such as [`parsimonious`](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious)) with a well-defined C++ grammar.

Comment: I thought about using third-party libraries for parsing, but I'm not sure that it will be an easy task for me. I thought it would be easier and faster to write a simple library than a complicated one. Do you think that using a library would be a good idea and it wouldn't take so much time?

Comment: It will take time to learn a library for sure, but definitely not more time than debugging all the corner cases for your fragile code with `in` and `index`, etc.

Comment: A regex could help: this one sort of does the job: `re.findall(r'if\(([^)]*)\)\{([^}]*)}(?:elseif\(([^)]*)\)\{([^}]*)})*?(?:else\{([^}]*)})?', code)`